# How to use AutoHotKey to act upon new files created in a folder?

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to have AutoHotKey listen/watch a folder on disk (let's say c:\folder) for any new files that are created there. If a new file show's up, the script should execute a set of commands:

`Send {Esc}
   Sleep, 100
   Send {F5}
   Sleep, 100
   Send {Home}
   Sleep, 100
   Send s
   Sleep, 100
   Send {Enter}
Return`

, after which it should go back to watching the folder for new changes and so on. I realize it should use the WatchDirectory() funtion, but don't know how to implement it. Any help? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WatchFolder()](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=8384) function, download it put it in the same place as your script and then you can do:

```
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\WatchFolder.ahk

WatchFolder("c:\folder", "myFunc", , Watch := 1)
return

myFunc(path, changes) {
    for k, change in changes
        ; 1 means new file was added
        if (change.action = 1) {
            gosub doStuff
            return
        }
}

doStuff:
; commands you want to execute
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I added your code and it doesn't want to work, the script seems not to load (no icon in task bar). My final code looks like this:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


#Include %A_ScriptDir%\WatchFolder.ahk

WatchFolder("C:\Users\kris\Desktop\temp", "myFunc", , Watch := 1)
return

myFunc(path, changes) {
for k, change in changes
    ; 1 means new file was added
    if (change.action = 1) {
        gosub doStuff
        return
    }
}

doStuff:
  Send {Esc}
  Sleep, 500
  Send {F5}
  Sleep, 100
  Send {Home}
  Sleep, 100
  Send s
  Sleep, 100
  Send {Enter}
return
```

I've inserted the WatchFolder.ahk in the same folder as the script.

Comment: That's because you don't have any hotkeys and it just exits. Add `#Persistent` at the beginning and it will continue to run.

Comment: Thx! Works like a charm :)